# Странное поведение free() в MinGW

Tags: c++, c, windows, отладка

Столкнулся с очень странной проблемой, которая связана, по всей видимости, с работой **free()** из состава **MinGW x32** и **MinGW x64**.

Все началось с языка **C** и функции, которая освобождает хэш-мультиотображение ото всех пар (узлов), вызывая для ключа и данных каждой пары простой **free()**.

Проблема заключалась в том, что при не очень большом количестве узлов программа как буд-то бы уходила в вечный цикл. Перерыв весь свой код, я заподозрил, что проблема кроется не в нем, а где-то уровнем ниже.

Методом проб мне удалось выяснить, что большое количество вызовов *маленьких* **free()** имеет НЕЛИНЕЙНЫЙ рост по сложности.

Вот график:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Судя по графику, **free()** или то, что он там внутри себя вызывает, имеет сложность, близкую к **O(n^2)**. И это странно. Я измерял время удаления не только всего связного списка, но и время **free()** для каждого узла.

*И с каждым узлом это время растет.*

Я пробовал использовать компиляторы **MinGW x32** и **MinGW x64**, проблема осталась и там, и там. **Debug/Release** так же не влияют на происходящее. Используемая операционная система - **Windows 10 x64**.

Сперва я был уверен, что проблема свойственна исключительно языку **C** и его стандартной реализации **free()**, но все же решил написать небольшую проверку, используя то, что точно работает - **std::forward_list**.

При использовании **C++** и **MinGW** результат оказался абсолютно идентичным.

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>
#include <time.h>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    clock_t t1, t2;
    {
        forward_list<unique_ptr<float>> list;

        t1 = clock();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 10 * 1000 * 1000; ++i)
        {
            unique_ptr<float> uf{ new float() };
            list.push_front(std::move(uf));
        }
        t2 = clock();

        cout << t2 - t1 << endl;

        t1 = clock();
    }

    t2 = clock();

    cout << t2 - t1 << endl;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Проблема та же - ОЧЕНЬ долгое удаление узлов и маленьких данных, которые в этих узлах хранятся. Выше приведенный код выполняется уже минут пять, а память освободилась только наполовину *600 Мб -> 320 МБ*.

Приведенный код на моем ржавом железе выводит:

```
42 177
870 000
```

Мы пробовали повторить тесты в **Visual Studio**, оказалось, что список удаляется даже быстрее, чем создается.

То есть, проблема квадратичной сложности свойственна компиляторам **MinGW**. В понедельник я еще проверю поведение **Clang**.

Я не понимаю, что происходит.

Может быть, в **MinGW** реализация **free()**, а так же **delete**/**delete[]**, содержит баг, из-за которого в **Windows 10** происходит описанный атас? Это ведь ненормально, что связный список из 10 000 000 узлов удаляется 15(!!!) минут.

Очень хотелось бы понять, с чем это связано, кто виноват и что делать.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81837/discussion-on-question-by----free).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

После долгих размышлений в чате под вопросом выяснилось, что автор банально запускал свой, хоть и релизный, билд с помощью дебаггера. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему это так плохо влияет в данном случае на скорость - разберемся ниже.

**Дисклеймер**

**Данный ответ относится только к ОС Windows, автор, судя по чату, тоже сидит на Windows. Есть ли Debug Heap на Unix/Linux и как там это все работает я не знаю. Если среди читающих это найдется знающий человек - с удовольствием прочту его ответ/дополнение к моему ответу по этому поводу.**

---

Запуск одинаковой программы в дебаггере и без него значительно снизит скорость ее работы, вернее сказать, скорость сильно зависит от кол-ва выделяемой памяти из кучи, будь то с помощью malloc или new.
**Почему?** Ответ прост:

### Debug Heap

В Windows существует специальная куча для отслеживания утечек памяти и прочих прелестей - речь сейчас не об этом. Суть в том, что дебаггер запускает приложение с помощью этой специальной кучи:

> Processes that the debugger creates (also known as spawned processes)
>   behave slightly differently than processes that the debugger does not
>   create. Instead of using the standard heap API, processes that the
>   debugger creates use a special debug heap.

[В данном случае нас интересует, что там с выделением и освобождением памяти. Все просто](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> The Debug versions of the heap functions call the standard or base
>   versions used in Release builds. When you request a memory block, the
>   debug heap manager allocates from the base heap a **slightly larger
>   block of memory than requested** and returns a pointer to your portion
>   of that block.For example, suppose your application contains the call:
>   malloc( 10 ). In a Release build, malloc would call the base heap
>   allocation routine requesting an allocation of 10 bytes. In a **Debug
>   build**, however, **malloc would call _malloc_dbg**, which would then call
>   the base heap allocation routine requesting an allocation of 10 bytes
>   plus approximately **36 bytes of additional memory**.

Вместо 10 байт мы получили в разы больше, это достаточно большой оверхед для 10ти байт, если выделять большие куски памяти самостоятельно их разделять - такой проблемы уже не будет. Да и выделять память пореже и большими кусками - в целом хорошая практика даже без дебаггера.

Вся эта дополнительная память уходит на, очевидно, информацию для дебага, конкретно, [для этой структуры](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
typedef struct _CrtMemBlockHeader  
{  
    // Pointer to the block allocated just before this one:  
    struct _CrtMemBlockHeader *pBlockHeaderNext;  
    // Pointer to the block allocated just after this one:  
    struct _CrtMemBlockHeader *pBlockHeaderPrev;  
    char *szFileName;    // File name  
    int nLine;           // Line number  
    size_t nDataSize;    // Size of user block  
    int nBlockUse;       // Type of block  
    long lRequest;       // Allocation number  
    // Buffer just before (lower than) the user's memory:  
   unsigned char gap[nNoMansLandSize];  
} _CrtMemBlockHeader;
```

Не вижу смысла углубляться, вопрос не об этом, да и лучше msdn я явно не объясню :)

---

**Что же мы видим у вас в коде?**

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10 * 1000 * 1000; ++i)
{
    unique_ptr<float> uf{ new float() };
    ...
}
```

**Миллионы** запросов выделить 4 байта. Это и без дебагов, скажем так, не особо круто, ну а с дебаггером - тихий ужас. Вы, как выразились на msdn, *приблизительно* выделяете (4 + 36) * 10 * 1.000 * 1.000 ~ 382мб вместо 38мб, не совсем понятно, почему такие цифры вас не смутили изначально. И это я молчу про то, что сам аллокатор тоже выделяет память для контроля и прочей системной мишуры.

Из таких расчетов следует 2 факта:

1. Понятно, почему выделялись такие объемы памяти, вы в своем же вопросе писали о 600мб.
2. Скорость работы malloc/free, new/delete напрямую зависит от того, как именно выделяется памяти.

В случае дебаггера - это много дебажной информации, которую тоже нужно выделить, причем отдельно от вашей памяти, а это как минимум 1 дополнительный вызов malloc/new и free/delete. Дебаггер при этом тоже использует ресурсы ЦП для управления всем этим. Более того, эти блоки для дебага памяти хранятся в виде двусвязного списка в порядке аллокации.

В данном примере память освобождается в обратном порядке, с чем двусвязный список справляется достаточно быстро, так что вам еще повезло. Был бы это какой-нибудь std::map - программа работала бы еще медленнее. Да и вы не указали конкретный код в вашем проекте, возможно, вы в разном порядке удаляете узлы - это тоже замедлит работу.

> All the resulting memory blocks in the debug heap are connected in a
>   single linked list, ordered according to when they were allocated.

---

В гугле полно примеров и одинаковых вопросов на эту тему, вот первый попавшийся пример быстродействия с дебажной кучей и без:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чем чаще вызывается аллокация памяти - тем медленнее работает программа в дебаггере.

---

### Как отключить Debug Heap?

Самый простой способ - не запускать приложение через дебаггер. Это можно сделать прямо в Visual Studio - Ctrl + F5.

Более "умные" способы:

1. Для отдельного проекта: присвоить переменной среды _NO_DEBUG_HEAP значение 1:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Для всех проектов: отключить **Enable Windows debug heap allocator (Native only)**:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее можно прочесть [по ссылке](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/10/06/c-debugging-improvements-in-visual-studio-14/). Скриншоты взяты оттуда же.

---

### Выводы

1. Программа под дебаггером всегда работает медленнее, ну уж точно не быстрее.
2. Запуск release версии в дебаггере - это все равно дебаг на уровне выделения памяти. Следит за этим ОС через ntdll.dll, который и проверяет без спроса, как запускается ваше приложение.
3. Кажется, что эту проблема можно вообще не решать - ведь конечное приложение будет запускаться без дебаггера. Да, это так. В чате уже писали про "выделяется страница, а конкретная реализация free/new управляет этим". Но тут возникает вопрос: а зачем вы вообще используете односвязный список для хранения float`ов? Только ради O(1) для вставки/удаления? Ну ради такой вставки использовать списки - плохая затея.

Comment: В Linux для отладки памяти [Valgrind](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind)

Comment: @Valgrind, благодарю. Почитал, логика работы примерно такая же, только на win это включено в дебаггере по умолчанию.

Comment: Дебажная куча используется даже в **release** только в **Windows 10**? Не помню такой проблемы на других версиях ОС-и.

Comment: **С++** и **std::forward_list** я использовал только для того, чтобы предоставить минимальный воспроизводимый пример, большую часть времени я пишу на **C**.

Comment: Ерунда была еще и в том, что в **Visual Stuio** по умолчанию и в дебажной, и в релизной версии описанное поведение не наблюдалось, это меня и сбило с толку.

Comment: @Максим, первые упоминания о debug heap относятся к .net 2003, видимо, это было доступно еще на windows xp. По поводу Си и С++ я написал: разницы нет, и malloc, и new заменяются на дебаг версии через ntdll.dll. По поводу VS: я немного напутал в ответе (уже исправил), по дефолту функция "Enable Windows debug heap allocator (Native only)" отключена. По логике вещей в VS дебаггер без спроса не будет подключать свою кучу. Но фишка в том, что эта куча заменяется на уровне ОС при порождении процесса с помощью определенным настроек, вот как раз такое поведение можно отключить через дебаггер.

Comment: @Максим, по поводу forward_list, это лишь объяснение на вашем примере. Как я написал в ответе: блоки дебажной кучи хранятся в виде двусвязного списка, вызывать free/delete в таком случае наиболее быстро будет в том порядке, в котором вы выделяли память (тут не уверен, да и инфы не то, что бы много, так что предположу, что дебаггер будет искать эти блоки с начала списка, а не с конца). Но, вообще говоря, у такого списка O(n) на удаление, так что вы могли нарваться в своем проекте на самый медленный вариант, что еще больше бы усугубило ситуацию.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: @avp, valgrind — это кое-что куда более крутое и мощное — он полностью эмулирует выполнение программы, что замедляет её выполнение на порядок, но зато даёт куда большие возможности: помимо поиска утечек это включает профилирование памяти/кеша/выполнения и многое куда менее впечатляющее... Аналог сабжа — это скорее [`dmalloc`](http://dmalloc.com/)